# Getting toggle player prefs to display in unity text field

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im having some trouble with displaying strings from playerprefs in text fields

```
public void ActiveToggle ()
{
    if (isNone.isOn)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("Offer_schedule","None");
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        Debug.Log("Offer_schedule".ToString());
    } else if (isDaily.isOn) {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("Offer_schedule","Daily");
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        Debug.Log("Offer_schedule".ToString());
    } else if (isWeekly.isOn) {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("Offer_schedule","Weekly");
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        Debug.Log("Offer_schedule".ToString());
    }
}

Offer_schedule =PlayerPrefs.GetString("Offer_schedule");
```

I save playerprefs offer schedule as a string based on toggle selected
offerschedule.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Offer_schedule");
I cannot get the string to display in text field

Comment: Debug.Log("Offer_schedule".ToString()); will always print "Offer_schedule"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake lays in the `Debug.Log("Offer_schedule".ToString());`

Here you are casting a [String literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) to a string. Which means you are just displaying the literal string `"Offer_schedule"`.

If you want to `Debug.Log()` the actual `PlayerPrefs` value You will either A:

```
// Debug the result from the GetString directly
Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Offer_schedule"));
```

or as you attempted in the code above B:

```
// Store our value in in a variable
string Offer_schedule = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Offer_schedule");
// Now display our variable
Debug.Log(Offer_schedule);
```

See how in the second example we are not using `"`, making it a call to the variable, as opposed to writing a literal.